# Blackberry BrowserField2Demo redirect

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I'm working with the JDE 7.1 in BrowserField2Demo and want to know how to intercept the "pre-load" event. The "OLD" BrowserFieldDemo had events such as "Event.EVENT_URL_REQUESTED" that would allow URL pre-load manipulations. Where do these events happen with "BrowserField2"?

Example: If the URL requested was "http://www.bing.com/" and I wished to re-direct it to "http://www.google.com/" where does this "pre-load" event happen?

Here is my code after a failed attempt which doesn't work:

---

```java
private BrowserField _browserField;    
private boolean _documentLoaded = false;
private BrowserFieldRequest _request;


/**
 * Creates a new BrowserFieldScreen object
 * @param request The URI of the content to display in this BrowserFieldScreen
 * @param enableScriptMenu True if a context menu is to be created for this BrowserFieldScreen instance, false otherwise
 */
public BrowserFieldScreen(BrowserFieldRequest request, boolean enableScriptMenu)
{    
    super(Screen.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

    BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();  
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, controller);
    _browserField = new BrowserField(config);
    add(_browserField);
    _request = request;        
}    


ProtocolController controller = new ProtocolController(_browserField)    
{    
    public void handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception    
    {    
        InputConnection inputConnection = handleResourceRequest(request);    
        _browserField.displayContent(inputConnection, request.getURL());    
    }    
};
```

---

What I see is that at the first time the `handleNavigationRequest` gets called is that it crashes with the error message saying

> Error request content for google.com error message null

with a **CLOSE** button. Then nothing happens.

Comment: You could try [something like this answer, that uses ProtocolController](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11927341/119114).  You could switch the URL being requested.

Comment: Thanks again Nate! I value your experience with my questions.

Comment: Ok, I copied the code from that link you suggested but I get an error when I run it on my Torch 9850.

>> I can't post code because it's too long <<

What happens when I use it is an error message shows: 
Error requesting content for: http://google.com
Error message null
<CLOSE>

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `public BrowserFieldScreen(BrowserFieldRequest request, boolean enableScriptMenu)    
{    
super(Screen.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);    
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();  
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);    
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);    
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);    
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, controller);    
_browserField = new BrowserField(config);    
add(_browserField);
_request = request;        
}`

Comment: `ProtocolController controller = new ProtocolController(_browserField)    
{    
    public void handleNavigationRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception    
    {    
    InputConnection inputConnection = handleResourceRequest(request);    
    _browserField.displayContent(inputConnection, request.getURL());    
    }    
};`

Comment: try using the **edit** link and posting the code into your question, instead of into the comments.  thanks

Comment: **What** doesn't work about the code you posted?  It doesn't ever call `handleNavigationRequest()`?  It doesn't redirect the URLs?  In the code you show, `handleNavigationRequest()` isn't attempting to change the URL. It's passing the original URL on, unmodified.  You also don't ever call `_browserField.requestContent(_request);`, so is the problem that you're just not seeing anything happen?  Please be specific.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of defining the problem. What I see is that at the first time the handleNavigationRequest gets called is that it crashes with the error message saying "Error request content for google.com error message null" with a <CLOSE> button. Then nothing happens. Where should the `_browserField.requestContent(_requests);` be placed? I must have missed that in the sample code I was ripping.

Comment: Ok, if you're getting the `handleNavigationRequest()` callback, then that means that `requestContent()` **is** being called.  If you haven't modified the sample code, I think it's called automatically when the screen loads (in `onUiEngineAttached()`).  So, that's not the problem.  I'm on my Mac now, so I can't run in the sims ... I'll try to double check the rest of your code later.

Comment: Ok, I see that maybe the call is originating from `BrowserField2Demo()
    {       
        try
        {            
            BrowserFieldRequest request = new BrowserFieldRequest("http://google.com");
            _browserScreen = new BrowserFieldScreen(request, true);
            extendJavaScript(_browserScreen.getBrowserField());
            pushScreen(_browserScreen);        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            errorDialog("An error occurred, exiting Webfilter: " + e.toString(), true);            
        }
    }`

Again, thanks for you help with my problem.

Comment: I also have the problem reference with the code more clearly posted at: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField2-handleNavigation-event/td-p/2214251 which maybe easier to read.

Comment: I figured out a working solution and posted it at: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField2-handleNavigation-event/td-p/2214251

Comment: Could you paste the solution you posted on supportforums.blackberry.com here, too, as an **answer**?  and then, mark that as the correct answer?  you'll get some points for doing so, and help others find the solution later, if blackberry.com links go stale.  thanks.