# Browser filed link click event

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

Hi I am developing an application in Blackberry java using Eclipse IDE. I have added a Browser Filed on the screen. And the Browser Filed contains many link  (). I want to know which link the user clicked and perform actions for each link. My question is how can i get click event for Browser Filed link.

Comment: Show some Code please..

Comment: I have solved this issue by using custom class. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924182/blackberry-5-0-browserfield-handle-link-clicked/12153989#12153989

Comment: amazing post.This works well. This is what i am looking for. Thank you very much............